# Both buttons opens same table in csv problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tkinter, tk-toolkit

These are two buttons

```
second_year_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"D:\Academy Management Application\Icons\2nd_year_icon.png")
global second_year_btn
second_year_btn = tk.Button(label_frame, font=LARGE_FONT, image=second_year_icon,
                      border=0 ,command=lambda : controller.show_frame(second_year) )
second_year_btn.grid(row=0 , column =0, padx=(10,10) , pady=(10,0), sticky=tk.E)


first_year_icon=tk.PhotoImage(file = r"D:\Academy Management 
Application\Icons\1st_year_icon.png")

        global first_year_btn
        first_year_btn = tk.Button(label_frame, font=LARGE_FONT, image=first_year_icon
                            , command=lambda : controller.show_frame(second_year), border=0 )
        first_year_btn.grid(row=0 , column =1, padx=(10,10) , pady=(10,0), sticky=tk.E)
```

Now if click first_year_btn it also show same data when I click second_year_btn. I know I am making some silly mistake but don't which one . I am very tens . Can please anyone help me ?

```
reader = DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if first_year_btn:
            if row['Class Name'] == '09th':
                registration_no= row['Registration No']
                student_name = row['Student Name']
                f_name = row['Father Name']
                gender = row['Gender']
                class_name =row['Class Name']
                class_session =row['Class Session']
                admission_date =row['Admission Date']
                monthly_fee = row['Monthly Fee']
                dues_payment=row['Dues']
                tree.insert("", 0, values=(registration_no, student_name, f_name,gender,class_name,class_session,admission_date,monthly_fee,dues_payment))
        elif  second_year_btn :

            if row['Class Name'] == 'Second Year':
                registration_no = row['Registration No']
                student_name = row['Student Name']
                f_name = row['Father Name']
                gender = row['Gender']
                class_name = row['Class Name']
                class_session = row['Class Session']
                admission_date = row['Admission Date']
                monthly_fee = row['Monthly Fee']
                dues_payment = row['Dues']
                tree.insert("", 0, values=(
                registration_no, student_name, f_name, gender, class_name, class_session, admission_date,
                monthly_fee, dues_payment))
```

Comment: Should it be `command=lambda: controller.show_frame(first_year)` for the `first_year_btn`?

Comment: class second_year(tk.Frame): I am using class method so it opens another frame , in that frame i am opening a table

Comment: I have option to create class for every button , but it will not follow DRY code , I want to create functionality for both buttons in single class

Comment: So how your code knows which button trigger the command?

Comment: Yes that is why I also asked this in previous question . I have a csv file . I want to read data from the that csv file , I am using class method , in first class I have created buttons , now in second class I want to show data according to the button which will be clicked , I am very tens . Because getting no idea how to do it

Comment: I want to define buttons functionality in this frame only

Comment: that was showing error to me

Comment: I think so year selected was not returning any value

Comment: Since `if first_year_btn:` is always true, so you get the same result.  And those code is executed when creating the frame and so what is shown will not be changed when you switch frame.  You should put those code in a function, and call it after switching frame.

Comment: Please help me with code

Comment: Your previous code was giving error year_selected is not define

Comment: Second problem is I am defining lamda function which does not return any value , so can I define a fucntion which can return or save a value and that value can be called in next class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple example based on your posted code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from csv import DictReader

class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
    mainframe.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for f in (main_page, second_year):
      frame = f(mainframe, self)
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
      self.frames[f] = frame
    self.show_frame(main_page)

  def show_frame(self, fclass):
      frame = self.frames[fclass]
      frame.tkraise()
      return frame

class main_page(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.controller = controller

    label_frame = tk.Frame(self)
    label_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    first_year_button = tk.Button(label_frame, text='First Year',
                                  width=20, command=lambda: self.select_year(1))
    first_year_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10,0))

    second_year_button = tk.Button(label_frame, text='Second Year',
                                   width=20, command=lambda: self.select_year(2))
    second_year_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10,0))

  def select_year(self, year):
    frame = self.controller.show_frame(second_year)
    frame.set_year(year)

class second_year(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    super().__init__(parent)

    columns = ('Reg #', 'Student Name', 'Father Name', 'Gender',
               'Class', 'Session', 'Admin. Fee', 'Monthly Fee', 'Dues')
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='headings', columns=columns)
    self.tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    for col in columns:
      self.tree.heading(col, text=col)
      self.tree.column(col, width=100, anchor='c')

  def set_year(self, year):
    if year == 1:
      filter = '09th'
    elif year == 2:
      filter = 'Second Year'
    else:
      filter = None
    if filter:
      with open('registration.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
          if row['Class Name'] == filter:
            registration_no= row['Registration No']
            student_name = row['Student Name']
            f_name = row['Father Name']
            gender = row['Gender']
            class_name = row['Class Name']
            class_session = row['Class Session']
            admission_date = row['Admission Date']
            monthly_fee = row['Monthly Fee']
            dues_payment = row['Dues']
            self.tree.insert('', 0, values=(registration_no, student_name, f_name, gender,
                                            class_name, class_session, admission_date,
                                            monthly_fee, dues_payment))

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are always genius , just only one problem left , if i clicked back button it does not remove data from tree and when I clicked another data it insert data in same tree , means that it insert data in same tree ,,, for example when I clicked second year button it insert second year data , when I clicked on back button and insert first year data it then insert first year data and also second year data also present in it

Comment: Add `self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())` before opening `registration.csv` file.  Or add it before going back to main page.

Comment: Yes done , again you are genius , just one last question I want to ask , let suppose I am using a practical application and I use this method that whenever I click on button it will delete data and after again clicking on it again it reload all data , is it ok ? or there is some better way to use it ?

Comment: Sorry I don't catch what you want.

Comment: I asking about this statement self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children()) ........ means that every time when I click on back button it deletes all data and insert new data , is it a good approach ? or is there any better way ?

Comment: for example if I have very large amount of data and each time I delete whole table and then reinsert data after each click , is it a good approach or their some better method to do it ...

Comment: This approach may not be efficient but the logic is simple.  Other way is to update affected rows and then either removing extra rows or inserting new rows based on the difference between old and new result size.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this kind of Structure,  MainFrameClass is your old class that is coming from Library or creating an old frame for you. it has some variables that are under use inside that frame.  Your task is to create new class, inherit old one into new. create new method through which you can only change those variables that you want to change inside frame.

```
class MainFrameClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hi, I am " + self.name)

class UpdatedClass(MainFrameClass):

    def show_name(self):
        print("Hi, I am " + self.name)

    def update_name(self,new_name):
        self.name = new_name

x = MainFrameClass("Old Variable Data Coming from Old Class")
y = UpdatedClass("New Variable Data Given to New Class")



y.show_name()
y.update_name('New Variable Data That was Updated Again')
y.show_name()
```

Comment: class second_year(tk.Frame): I am using class method so it opens another frame , in that frame i am opening a table 
I have option to create class for every button , but it will not follow DRY code , I want to create functionality for both buttons in single class

Comment: You don't want to open another Frame every time you call your  class?

Comment: yes yes, , I want to define the button functionality in same this frame only

Comment: Okay, Class instance controller.show_frame is configured to create new frame every time you call it, Don't do it this way.  Best option would be to use procedural programming for tkinter where you change content of once created frame instead of calling show_frame every time. Even if you want to go with the beauty of OOP, then probably, you'll have to Inherit main Class, and do few changes with its method .show_frame.  Best Option would be to go Procedural, ( Create Frame once, and change its content again and again.

Comment: My program have multiple pages , have multiple functions , if I will go in procedual way my code will mess up and almost I have done my half of application , I want to follow DRY principle , please if you can just do this in this code

Comment: Okay, then you can inherit your main Class into you updated one having all the methods and functions same through super keyword method. You'll be supposed to define some new variables that you want to change inside created frame or variables that your created frame uses. Now Define another function / method of class update_changes(*all, your, inputs, that , you, want, to , change):    and here replace all those variables values that are being used by your Frame method to insert data.

Comment: better it would be if I see some kind of code example

Comment: Updated my answer with dummy code, Check that out and follow the structure in your situation.